# Can't upload Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, upload, php-ini

I tried to upload and install new plugin on my website [Webmaster Offers](http://www.webmasteroffers.com) but I get error:

```
Files larger than 500 kilobytes are not allowed
```

I set max upload file size in Cpanel is 16Mb, no php.ini file in my root folder or public_html

No block via .htaccess

Disabled all plugins but still same problems

Search around the Google but can't find the answer

Do you known why and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Strange issue… Is not a solution to that issue but try to upload unzipped plugin via FTP then. How you have tried to uploaded it (there is 2 ways in wordpress)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to the following.

1.] Put the code below in your theme's functions.php.

```
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '16M');
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '16M' );
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '180' );
```

2.] Put the code below in your .htaccess

```
php_value post_max_size 16M
php_value upload_max_filesize 16M
php_value max_input_time 180
php_value max_execution_time 180
```

Also you can check your Wordpress' max upload size by going to your dashboard media - http://www.yoursite.com/wp-admin/upload.php and you can see the max upload size there.